# How do I play an FLV file in Haxe?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flv, haxe

It is very difficult to find good resources for Haxe information so I am hoping someone out there can help me. I have an FLV movie in the same directory as the SWF I am generating. I cannot get the FLV to play. I can get this working in AS but I need to know what I am doing wrong in my Haxe code.

Hope someone can help.

```
var mc:MovieClip = Lib._root;       

var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
connection.connect(null);
var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(connection);

mc.attachVideo(stream);
trace(mc.flash.Video);
stream.play("default.flv");
```

Comment: Take a look at a new open source project, [rtmpPlayer](https://github.com/mikkun/rtmpPlayer). It should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Google Code project that demos a nice flash media server. It plays and even records videos. http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently different from Haxe and AS when it comes to play video as you would be using AS libraries. To which player are you compiling to? Because if you are compiling to player >= 9 you are missing a few bits.

You can check out my example of AS3 player [here](http://code.google.com/p/zcode/source/browse/trunk/as3/tv/zarate/player/video/ZVideo.as) (scroll down to `createVideo()`) to find out exactly what (create the Video object, attach to the display list, etc).

I'm also guessing that you are not getting any compiler errors, right?

Juan

Answer (score 0):

What player version do you target? For 10 the stage is `flash.Lib.current`.
Do haxe compiler says something about errors?